# Trying to copy column, based on header, from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to have VBA open up a selected workbook and copy the column of data based on the heading "RGRD".  The code fails after selecting the EntireColumn with a Run Time Error 424.  I would prefer to copy down until the last non empty cell in the column.

```
Sub test()

Dim wkbCrntWorkBook As Workbook
Dim wkbSourceBook As Workbook

Dim rngSourceRange As Range
Dim rngDestination As Range
Dim rngTest1 As Range

Dim strFindThis As String

Set wkbCrntWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook

'Opens prompt to select Source file
With Application.fileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
.Filters.Clear
.Filters.Add "Excel 2007", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa", 1
.Filters.Add "Excel 2002-03", "*.xls", 2
.AllowMultiSelect = False
.Show

If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
    Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(1)

    Set wkbSourceBook = ActiveWorkbook

    'Code searches for key word
    strFindThis = "RGRD"
    Set rngSourceRange = Application.Range("A1:BZ1").Find(What:=strFindThis, Lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)

    'Selects entire column based on key word header
    Set rngTest1 = rngSourceRange.EntireColumn.Select

    'Swicthes to UMD Price Out Worksbook
    wkbCrntWorkBook.Activate

    'Copies column data from Source to Cell B1 on UMD Price Out Workbook
    Set rngDestination = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2)
    rngTest1.Copy rngDestination

    'Formats column to AutFit and Closes Source Worksbook
    rngDestination.CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    wkbSourceBook.Close False

End If
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is on this line:

```
Set rngTest1 = rngSourceRange.EntireColumn.Select
```

One statement can execute only one action, but this line performs 2, generating the error:

- `rngSourceRange.EntireColumn.Select` - this selects the column
- `Set rngTest1 = ...` - this attempts to set the range object

To fix your code just remove `.Select`

In the code bellow I use more descriptive variable names, eliminated the Select and Activate actions, and check that the string (column) is found

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyRGRD()
    Const FIND_STR = "RGRD"

    Dim destWb As Workbook, srcWb As Workbook, srcUR As Range, destCell As Range
    Dim foundCell As Range, foundCol As Range

    Set destWb = Application.ThisWorkbook   'File where the code executes

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel 2007", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa", 1
        .Filters.Add "Excel 2002-03", "*.xls", 2
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Set srcWb = Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(1))
            Set srcUR = srcWb.Worksheets(1).UsedRange   'Sheet1 in selected file

            Set foundCell = srcUR.Rows(1).Find(What:=FIND_STR, _
                                               Lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)

            If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then    'Make sure that column RGRD exists
                Set foundCol = srcUR.Columns(foundCell.Column).EntireColumn
                Set destCell = destWb.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2)
                foundCol.Copy destCell
                destCell.EntireColumn.AutoFit
            End If
            srcWb.Close False
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Excel 2010 or later, try formatting your data as a Table, using Insert > Table!!!

[image: Table]

This makes your data into a growing ActiveSheet.Listobject which has [all kinds of features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/listobject-object-excel) in VBA that you can use, including a pre-calculated number of rows.